# I added it to my project but I can't import it in code

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I added it to my project but I can't import it in code

build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
 implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
 implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
 implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

Comment: What error if any you are getting and what code in java/kotlin are you trying? You need to be more specific and add more details in order to be helped. This scenario can map to multiple issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to the settings.graddle and it should work properly

Comment: Thanks, I've never done it that way, but the "old" way in build.gradle no longer works

Answer (score 3):

Add the repository under "dependencyResolutionManagement" not "pluginManagement".

Answer (score 1):

In settings.gradle file --

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

In build.gradle file --

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```